# How to bind second parameter in scala curry function?

Tags: scala, currying

```
//a curry function
def find(a: Seq[Int])(sort: (Int, Int) => Boolean)

//My attempt
val findWithBiggerSort = find(_)((a,b) => a > b)
```

The `findWithBiggerSort` can't work, a compiler error occurred:

```
scala> def find(a: Seq[Int])(sort: (Int, Int) => Boolean)
     | ={}
find: (a: Seq[Int])(sort: (Int, Int) => Boolean)Unit

scala> val findWithBiggerSort = find(_)((a,b) => a > b)
<console>:11: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => find(x$1)(((a, b) => a.$greater(b))))
       val findWithBiggerSort = find(_)((a,b) => a > b)
                                     ^
```

how can I bind the second curry parameter?
how about bind second parameter as this

```
def find(a: Seq[Int], b: String)(sort: (Int, Int) => Boolean)
```

Comment: the `(a,b) => if (a > b) a else b` returns `Int` but should return `Boolean` according to signature

Comment: yes, should be (a,b) => a > b instead of `if` statement, I fixed it for clear the question.

Comment: What does "can't work" mean? Are you getting a compiler error?

Comment: @Jordan Parmer, It's a compiler error, I added it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two issues:

The type of your `sort` function is wrong - you need a `(Int, Int) => Boolean` but you provide an `(Int, Int) => Int`. If you change it to:

```
val findWithBiggerSort = find(_)((a,b) => (a > b))
```

you get an error for a missing type of the `_` parameter provided in `find (_)`. If you provide this type it compiles i.e.

```
val findWithBiggerSort = find(_:Seq[Int])((a,b) => (a > b))
```

or

```
val findWithBiggerSort = find(_:Seq[Int])(_ > _)
```

Comment: thanks point my error, and a further question is how about the `find(a: String, b: String)(sort: (Int, Int) => Boolean)` ?

Comment: ooh, just `find(_:String,_:String)(_  > _)` , I am seems some stupid